# Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <301>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, minitest

I have application without tests, now I'm trying to add them (minitest-rails), but something wrong.
I'm typing `rails generate controller test test`
and I have:

```
require "minitest_helper"
class TestControllerTest < MiniTest::Rails::ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get test" do
    get :test
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

now I'm typing `rake test` and `Expected response to be a <success>, but was <301>` error occuring.
Where is the problem?

**Edited:**
My controller's code:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def test
  end
end
```

Comment: @apneadiving but why any redirection happens?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it! Just deleted `force_ssl` and added `config.force_ssl = true` in production config.